# Boundary point of a filled in plane donut

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the set $$M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid 0< \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 1\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$$

Recall a boundary point $p \in M$ is a point such that for every ball around $p$ there exists a point $q \in M^c$

The question to prove or disprove that $(0,0)$ is a boundary point of $M$.

I tried to find $M^c$, which gives me $\mathbb{R}^2/B_1\cup\{(0,0)\} \cap \mathbb{R}^2/\{(0,0)\}$, where $B_1$ is the open ball of radius $1$. So this is equivalent $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the open ball centered at $(0,0)$. Then $(0,0)$ is a boundary point...however intuitively this does not seem to be true.

Can someone help me provide a better argument?

Comment: So..., isn't your set just an open disk with $(0,0)$ fully in the interior?

Comment: Yes, $M^c$ is $\Bbb R^2$ without the unit open ball centered at $(0,0)$. How does this imply that $(0,0)$ is a boundary point?

Comment: @MarkMcClure But is it? That's the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(0,0)$ is most definitely not a boundary point of $M$: trust your geometric intuition; your set is a disk with its boundary removed.

Supposing that you didn't know that, consider the open ball centered at zero, and radius $1$: $B(0, 1)$. Then, $B(0,1) \subset M$, in fact, $B(0,1) = M$. Thus, there exist a neighborhood of $0$, namely $B(0,1) = M$ for which no point in $B(0,1)$ lies in $M^c$.

I think one crucial thing that you are missing in your definition of boundary point is that the neighborhood around $p$ is required to contain the point in said complement.